# minio file upload in react js

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, minio

I encountered an issue with **opening a file** that I **uploaded** to a **Minio Bucket**. Here's the process I followed: I received the file from the **user**, converted it to **base64**, then converted it to a **buffer**. I successfully saved the file using the **putObject** API in **Minio**, but now I'm **unable to open the file**. If anyone has experience with this problem, could you please provide guidance on what steps I should take to resolve it?

//My function

```
 const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(); //The file selected by the user is stored in the fileData state.

 const uploadObj = () => {

    const fileBuffer = new FileReader();
    fileBuffer.readAsDataURL(fileData);

    fileBuffer.onload = function () {
      let buf = Buffer.from(fileBuffer.result, "base64"); //buffer data

      mc.putObject("BucketName", "FileName", buf, function (err, etag) {
        return console.log(err, etag); // err should be null
      });
    };
    fileBuffer.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my mistake. That error is readAsDataURL. Please change it to readAsArrayBuffer and it works fine.

more info about FileReader [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
 const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(); //The file selected by the user is stored in the fileData state.


 const uploadObj = () => {

    const fileBuffer = new FileReader();
    fileBuffer.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);

    fileBuffer.onload = async function () {
      let buf = Buffer.from(fileBuffer.result, "base64"); //buffer data

      await mc.putObject("hello", "FileName", buf, function (err, etag) {
        return console.log(err, etag); // err should be null
      });
    };
    fileBuffer.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    };
  }
```